# Is there a way to change s3 prefix to lowercase

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, bigdata, aws-glue, amazon-athena

I have a partitioned glue table and the data is stored in s3. partitioned on two columns, runid/DATE=xxxx

Is there easy way to convert the DATE column into lowercase?

I have tried to read all the partitions and the rename the partition columns and write it back but that's a long process. Looking for a simpler way